# ¿Cómo aplico el mismo estilo a todos los elementos '<td>' de un mismo '<tr>'?

Tags: html, css

este código se aplica a toda la fila cuando me pongo por encima, afectando a todas las celdas de esa fila:

```
tr:hover td {
    background-color: red;
    color: blue;
}
```

Lo que necesito conseguir es que se aplique a toda la columna cuando me pongo por encima de una celda, afectando así a todas las celdas de esa columna.

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Revisa [este código](https://codepen.io/davesantos/pen/mdZmyq).

Comment: Muchas gracias y si quisiera poner color a la letra de todos los td de la columna seleccionada como lo haría?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Siguiendo los ejemplos que te comentaron, el resultado final de tu tabla sería algo como:

```css
table {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #999;
  padding: 10px;
  position: relative;
}

tr td:hover::after { 
  background-color: red;
  content: '';  
  height: 10000px;    
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;  
  top: -5000px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;        
}

td:hover { 
  color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Columna 1</th>
    <th>Columna 2</th>
    <th>Columna 3</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Fila 1</td>
    <td>Fila 1</td>
    <td>Fila 1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Fila 2</td>
    <td>Fila 2</td>
    <td>Fila 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Fila 3</td>
    <td>Fila 3</td>
    <td>Fila 3</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @Aphans coméntame aquí, cual height te refieres? el ancho de los tD? puedes reducir el padding...

Comment: Es lo que te comenté en el otro comentario

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo un ejemplo de cómo resolverlo.

```
table {
  overflow: hidden;
}
td,
th {
  position: relative;
}
td:hover::after,
th:hover::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ffa;
  left: 0;
  top: -5000px;
  height: 10000px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

Más información en esta página.
https://css-tricks.com/simple-css-row-column-highlighting/

Comment: Muchas gracias y si quisiera poner color a la letra de todos los td de la columna seleccionada como lo haría?

Comment: No funciona, puedes comprobarlo. Aparte necesito que las columnas pares tengan un background por defecto de otro color y que se aplique el código de respuesta para ellas también

Comment: @Aphans te hice una respuesta en base a lo que querías, me avisas.

Comment: @Cris223511.dev Justo lo que deseaba, pero necesito que el height no se ve tan alto porque se me ve muy feo y sobresale del tr

Comment: Veo que en tu ejemplo se ejecuta bien, pero que pasa si tienes un caption arriba de la tabla?

Comment: Me refiero a que después de la etiqueta table tengas una etiqueta caption

Comment: Bueno, eso lo podrías pedir haciendo otra pregunta, ya que lo que pides es totalmente diferente a la pregunta aquí.

Comment: Lo solventé poniendo un background blanco al caption, pero muchas gracias!